# Vector multiply function in scheme, manipulating initial recursive parameter

Tags: recursion, lambda, scheme, racket

I've been working on a vector multiply function in scheme and have found myself in rut. I dont want to use any looping and I dont want to use any scheme built in functions other than the ones I've already included. I've created a helper function called rotate and dotproduct. I can get the correct values if I do this in racket `(vectormult '(1 2 -1) (rotate '((0 2 3) (1 2 0) (1 0 3))))`. **How can I rotate the initial parameter without re-rotating after every recursive call?** NOTE: I dont want to introduce additional paramaters. **If my logic/approach to this is all wrong please help me get on the right track.**

## Code

```
(define dotproduct
  (lambda (l1 l2)
    (if (or (null? l1) (null? l2))
        0
        (+ (* (car l1) (car l2)) (dotproduct (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))))

(define getFirsts
  (lambda (l)
    (cond
      ((null? l) `())
      (else (cons (first* l) (getFirsts (cdr l)))))))

(define removeFirsts
  (lambda (l)
    (cond
      ((null? l) `())
      ((null? (car l)) `())
      (else (cons  (cdr (car l)) (removeFirsts (cdr l)))))))

(define rotate
  (lambda (l)
    (cond
      ((null? l) `())
      ((null? (first* l)) `())
      (else (cons (getFirsts l) (rotate (removeFirsts l)))))))

(define vectormult
  (lambda (l1 l2)
    (cond
      ((null? l2) `())
      (else (cons (dotproduct l1 (car l2)) (vectormult l1 (cdr l2)))))))
```

Comment: `vectormult` does not appear to call `rotate`; where are these extra rotations coming from?

Comment: I want to utilize the rotate function in vectormult so I don't have to call it in the parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching the rotate function in favor of adding 2 functions `getFirsts` and `removeFirsts`.

## Code

```
(define getFirsts
  (lambda (l)
    (cond
      ((null? l) `())
      (else (cons (first* l) (getFirsts (cdr l)))))))

(define removeFirsts
  (lambda (l)
    (cond
      ((null? l) `())
      ((null? (car l)) `())
      (else (cons  (cdr (car l)) (removeFirsts (cdr l)))))))

;(define rotate
;  (lambda (l)
;    (cond
;      ((null? l) `())
;      ((null? (first* l)) `())
;      (else (cons (getFirsts l) (rotate (removeFirsts l)))))))

(define vectormult
  (lambda (l1 l2)
    (cond
      ((null? (first* l2)) `())
      (else (cons (dotproduct l1 (getFirsts l2)) (vectormult l1 (removeFirsts l2)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you could rename your current `vectormult` to, say, `rotatedvectormult` (and change its recursive call accordingly), and then have `vectormult` just rotate the parameter before calling `rotatedvectormult`.  This way, `rotatedvectormult` would know the parameter was already rotated, but `vectormult` could still take an unrotated vector.